# Why this LINQ to XML doesn't work?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I receive this XML from an external source:

```
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
  <response>
    <result code="1300">
      <msg>Command completed successfully; no messages</msg>
    </result>
    <trID>
      <clTRID>TEST-12345</clTRID>
      <svTRID>IRNIC_2011-09-21T13:44:25+04:30_f1u</svTRID>
    </trID>
  </response>
</epp>
```

I want to extract the **value** of the **code attribute** of the **result element**. I used this code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response);
XNamespace ns = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0";
string value = doc.Descendants(ns + "result").First().Attribute("code").Value;
```

However, it throws null value exception, because `doc.Descendants(ns + "result")` is null.

What's wrong here?

Comment: `Descendants("urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0result")`? Is that right?

Comment: Looks fine to me - have you inspected'doc' with the debugger to verify that it is the XML document you have included above?

Comment: @ColinE, yeah, it's valid and everything is as I've posted here.

Comment: I have just put this in a unit test and it works fine for me!

Comment: @bzlm - the first part is a namespace, not a string - XNamespace. The result element is in the namespace, so this is correct.

Comment: @Saeed: could you post the exact exception + stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

> However, it throws null value exception, because doc.Descendants(ns + "result") is null

I would not expect `doc.Descendants` to *ever* return a `null` - it might return an empty sequence, but that wouldn't be a "null value exception". Likewise, `First()` - it either returns *something*, or it throws an exception (and while that "something" can be a `null`, I do not expect `Descendants` would be yielding `null`s). So that leaves `.Attribute("code").Value`. Now yes; `.Attribute("code")` **can** return a `null`, if an attribute doesn't exist. If you are happy to obtain a `null` in those cases, I recommend:

```
string value = (string)doc.Descendants(ns + "result").First().Attribute("code");
```

the conversion operator handles null (non-existent) attributes.

Answer (score 1):

No repro. Your code is basically OK.

So: Debug. Break the statement up and check things.

- is your `doc` loaded OK ?
- what does just `doc.Descendants(ns + "result").First()` deliver?
- etc

Answer (score 1):

Check `response` variable because i loaded the xml from an xml file and your code worked great.

In case of testing, you can save the response in an xml file and load it from there.

use `XDocument.Load("a.xml")` to load an xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Tested this too. Easiest way to test is to download LinqPad, create new query, then for Language select "C# statement(s)" from the dropdown. Click Run, should work with the code provided. I would also check the response variable as suggested by "Rased Dot Net"

```
string xml =
@"<epp xmlns=""urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"">
  <response>
    <result code=""1300"">
      <msg>Command completed successfully; no messages</msg>
    </result>
    <trID>
      <clTRID>TEST-12345</clTRID>
      <svTRID>IRNIC_2011-09-21T13:44:25+04:30_f1u</svTRID>
    </trID>
  </response>
</epp>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
Console.WriteLine("Namespace: " + ns.ToString());
string value = doc.Descendants(ns + "result").First().Attribute("code").Value;
Console.WriteLine(value);
```